# MySql database to Microsoft Server Managemant Studio

Tags: mysql

I have installed ODBC driver in order import Mysql database to MS sql Management Studio but still not connecting. What should I do?

Comment: mysql workbench is for mysql ms sql management studio is for T-SQL unless you are trying to convert mysql into T-sql you are going to  need to write the app or find one online

Comment: Provider more detail about your environment, OS, software installed, etc. What if any errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You have installed MS SQL Management Studio which can connect with MS SQL Server to manage, create objects etc. There is nothing you should do from MS SQL M Studio to MySQL Server.

You have to install MySQL Workbench (free) to do your job. You have to install MySQL Workbench, export your data from it to '.sql' and then import it into your MS SQL Server after converting the SQL format from MySQL to MSSQL.

**OPTION 2**

Create MS Access database. Link both MS SQL Server's tables as well as MySQL Server's tables in it. (MS Access works great with MySQL Server).

Do simple copy and paste from one table (say MySQL S) to other (say  MS SQL S) within MS Access.